# Is it possible to enforce usage of specific library version through the whole project?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, snyk

I'm trying to fix some vulnerabilities in my program found by Snyk tool, but some of them are coming from libraries I'm using (like Apache's Pulsar).
For example, Pulsar is using version 2.8.6 of gson, which is vulnerable according to Snyk, and the next safe version is 2.8.9.
Is it possible to enforce all libraries I'm using to use version 2.8.9 of gson (through gradle)? Or rather not because it's a really stupid idea prone to unexpected behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a reasonable thing to want to do.  A new version of pulsar which officially supports the upgraded library would be better, but you can often upgrade transitive dependencies safely. Particularly, point releases (i.e. 2.8.6 -> 2.8.9) are likely to be safe if library authors are following semantic versioning.

Gradle provides several ways to do this, it seems like the most idomatic way right now (as of gradle 7.3)  is to use constraints.

For example, if your dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-client-all:2.9.1'
}
```

Running dependency insights will show that we're resolving gson 2.8.6

```
`./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency gson`


...

com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6
\--- org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-package-core:2.9.1
     \--- org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-client-all:2.9.1
          \--- compileClasspath
```

We can add a constraint which will force it to use a newer version like this.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-client-all:2.9.1'
  constraints {
        implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9') {
            because 'previous versions have a security vulnerability'
        }
  }
}
```

Now we get the following result

```
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9
...
   Selection reasons:
      - By constraint : previous versions have a security vulnerability
      - By conflict resolution : between versions 2.8.9 and 2.8.6

com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9
\--- compileClasspath

com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6 -> 2.8.9
\--- org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-package-core:2.9.1
     \--- org.apache.pulsar:pulsar-client-all:2.9.1
          \--- compileClasspath
```

It's now resolving 2.8.9 like you want.

Gradle has pretty extensive [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html) about dependency management which is a great way to find more information about things like this.

Comment: That's good to hear. I managed to get to the part where all my project's gson version were 2.8.x -> 2.8.9 but when I ran Snyk on the new project it still failed claiming it still find the older version.
Are you sure the -> means it will use the new provided version? And that it probably just sees the older version files inside the project?
Thank you

Comment: I don't know how exactly Snyk works.  What does it look at?  If it just looks at all your dependencies directly it might see that one is including 2.8.6 and not know that you've overridden it?  Also, how are you packaging your library?  You should be able to look in your POM and see what dependencies it's specifying.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure that this is a good idea , I think its a better idea to update the Apache's Pulsar version that depends on a stable version of gson .

but still am not 100% sure , wait for other for clarification .

still what you want can be done like the following

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
}
```

This will exclude all the gson with version 2.8.6 across the project .

then you can add the following version as you want

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
```